# Eigenspace associated to $A^{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If $H$ is the eigenspace associated to the eigenvalue $\lambda$ of the invertible matrix $A$, then $H$ is the eigenspace associated to the eigenvalue $\lambda^{-1}$ of $A^{-1}$?

I think the answer is yes. My try is as follows.

Let be $\lambda$ an eigenvalue associated to an invertible matrix $A$. Then, we know, $\lambda^{-1}$ is an eigenvalue associated to $A^{-1}$.

Now, suppose that $v \in \operatorname{Ker}(A-\lambda I)$. So
\begin{align} 
(A-\lambda I)\,v = 0 
&\implies (A^{-1}A - \lambda A^{-1}I)\,v = 0 \\ 
&\implies (A^{-1} - \lambda^{-1}I)\,v = 0 \\ 
&\implies v \in \operatorname{Ker}(A^{-1} - \lambda^{-1} I) 
\end{align}
and then
$\operatorname{Ker}(A-\lambda I) \subset \operatorname{Ker}(A^{-1} - \lambda^{-1} I)$.

The back works too. So
$\operatorname{Ker}(A^{-1} - \lambda^{-1} I) \subset 
\operatorname{Ker}(A - \lambda I)$, thus,
$$
\operatorname{Ker}(A^{-1} - \lambda^{-1} I) 
= \operatorname{Ker}(A - \lambda I). 
$$

Comment: Have you had a think about this? Show us your try, even if it's a dead end.

Comment: I just post my try. I think the answer is yes.

Comment: $A = P^{-1}DP \implies A^{-1} = (P^{-1}DP)^{-1} = P^{-1}D^{-1}P$

Comment: Good for showing work. I think you're overcomplicating things, though. Cross-dividing $Av=\lambda v$ yields $\lambda^{-1}v=A^{-1}v$, and cross-multiplying goes the other way.

Comment: @runway44 It's not so simple. For example, if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue associated to matrix $A$, $H_1 =Ker(A-\lambda I)$ and $H_2=Ker(A^2-\lambda^2 I)$, we have, in general, $H_1 \neq H_2$.

Comment: @DougM and what?

Comment: You seem to be interpreting my comment as blindly assuming the $\lambda^n$ eigenspace of $A^n$ must be the same as the $\lambda$ eigenspace for $A$ for any power $n$ (your example being $n=2$). I make no such blind assumption. It really is just as simple as my first comment shows. Unlike in the $n=2$ case, containment (of eigenspaces) goes both ways because you can reverse cross-division with cross-multiplation and vice-versa.

Comment: @runway44 I disagree. Your simple argument does not convince me.

Comment: I posted it as an answer. Feel free to point out where you are confused.

Comment: @runway44 Now works for me. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Saying "the $\lambda$-eigenspace of $A$ is the same as the $\lambda^{-1}$-eigenspace of $A^{-1}$" is the same as saying "any $\lambda$-eigenvector of $A$ is also a $\lambda^{-1}$-eigenvector of $A^{-1}$ and vice-versa."

Suppose $v$ is a $\lambda$-eigenvector of $A$. That is, $Av=\lambda v$. If we "cross-divide," or in other words multiply by $A^{-1}$ and $\lambda^{-1}$, this equation becomes $\lambda^{-1}v=A^{-1}v$, meaning $v$ is a $\lambda^{-1}$-eigenvector of $A^{-1}$. Conversely, if $v$ is a $\lambda^{-1}$-eigenvector of $A^{-1}$, then we can cross-multiply $\lambda^{-1}v=A^{-1}v$ to get $Av=\lambda v$, so $v$ is also a $\lambda$-eigenvector of $A$.

And thus the claim is proved.

Comment: Now works for me. Thank you.

Comment: The result is even stronger. Since powers of the scalar $\lambda$ and matrix $A$ commute with each other, the space of generalized $\lambda$-eigenvectors of $A$ of a given degree is precisely the space of generalized $\lambda^{-1}$-eigenvectors of $A^{-1}$, i.e. for any $k \geq 1$
$$
v \in \operatorname{ker} (A - \lambda I)^k = 0 
\iff 
v \in \operatorname{ker} (A^{-1} - \lambda^{-1} I)^k = 0
$$